# Creando columna por medio de JPA y la crea en medio de "

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

Estoy creando una columna por medio de JPA llamada position y al correr mi programa, en la base de datos se crea la columna dentro de Comillas dobles. Mi duda es ¿por qué hace eso?. les muestro la entidad donde está la columna `

```
@EmbeddedId CompositeSourceFilexIndex pk_source_file_index;

@MapsId("fileid")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns (foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_sourcefileIndex"), 
value = { @JoinColumn(name = "fileid", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private SourceFile sourcefile_index;

@Column(name = "position")
private Long position;
```

}`
En postgresql se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si cambio el nombre de la columna position a otro, ya no aparecen las comillas dobles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguro es una tontería pero si alguien puede aclarármela se lo agradecería.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una regla mnemotécnica en inglés para el uso de las comillas en SQL:

> **S**ingle quotes are for **S**trings ; **D**ouble quotes are for **D**atabase identifiers

Se traduce como: Comillas simples para Strings, comillas dobles para identificadores de la base de datos.

Por tanto las comillas dobles se usan para expresar que lo que está entre ellas es un identificador, aunque no cumpla el estándar:

Por ejemplo, podríamos crear una tabla cuyo nombre tuviera mayúsculas:

```
create table "MiTabla" ( ... )
```

Por defecto, SQL no diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, pero con las comillas dobles se expresa que el nombre es literalmente "MiTabla" y no "mitabla".

O también si usas como nombre de tabla una palabra que en PostgreSQL tiene otros usos, también se pondrá entre comillas para evitar problemas:

```
select * from "COUNT" where ... --No estamos usando la función count
```

En tu caso, estás creando un campo con el identificador `"position"`, que es también el nombre de una [función](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html), así que Hibernate se *cura en salud* entrecomillándola.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!